# Bibtex, 2 questions about pages in my Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am writing my master thesis, and got one problem with the bibtex.
below is a mini example: first, I create a folder, in the folder, there are a mini_example.txt , a thesis.bib file, a folder called include

```
\input{include/00-0-header}
\begin{document}
\include{include/01-introduction}
% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

thesis.bib is like this,

```
@inproceedings{erdmann2013modeling,
  title={Modeling studies on alternative EUV mask concepts for higher NA},
  author={Erdmann, Andreas and Fuehner, Tim and Evanschitzky, Peter and Neumann, Jens Timo and Ruoff, Johannes and Graeupner, Paul},
  booktitle={SPIE Advanced Lithography},
  pages={{86791Q--86791Q}},
  year={2013},
  organization={International Society for Optics and Photonics}
}



@article{fuhner2007direct,
  title={Direct optimization approach for lithographic process conditions},
  author={F{\"u}hner, Tim and Erdmann, Andreas and Seifert, Sebastian},
  journal={Journal of Micro/Nanolithography, MEMS, and MOEMS},
  volume={6},
  number={3},
  pages={{031006--031006}},
  year={2007},
  publisher={International Society for Optics and Photonics}
}
```

the folder 'include' has 2 files, first,  00-0-header.tex and 01-introduction.tex
00-0-header.tex is like this,

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{listings}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

01-introduction.tex is like this,

```
solution\cite{fuhner2007direct}. 


genetic algorithms integrated \cite{erdmann2013modeling}.
```

and what I got is, [image: prefer no pages] 
I prefer no pages,just numbers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! So you don't want to get the word ‘pages’; do you want an abbreviation or nothing at all. For your second request, I don't see clearly what you want to have.

Comment: @Bernard  Thanks! I edited my post based on your comment. I would like to have no 'pages', no abbreviation, just the numbers. For the second question, I would like to have one dash between the two numbers, not two dashes

Comment: And your second example should be `86791Q-1 –86791Q-12` (with a rather special numbering of pages)?

Comment: @andesgame The code you've provided isn't sufficient information. Which style are you using for displaying the bibliography? There are several. Please provide a minimal working example (MWE). If you don't know what is MWE, please see: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/78565

Comment: Let me echo @Amar's request: To properly diagnose the situation (and thus to be able to come up with a remedy), it's crucial for you to tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: @andesgame It's been a while since both answers were posted here and there's no more recent activity. Would you mind upvoting, replying and accepting one of the answers now?

Answer (score 1):

@andesgame Thanks for updating your original question with code. You seem to have provided just enough material to see the exact problem.

Here's my solution, where I have used necessary bits from your code to find and solve the problem.

As I see it, your problem has to do with the fact that you are using `@inproceedings` for the particular citation, where you don't want the word "pages" printed in your bibliography. Apparently, it is the inherent nature of certain bibliographic `@type`s to print the word "pages" in the displayed bibliography. Some of these `@type`s include - `@inproceedings`, `@inbook`, `@incollection`, etc. For more information on bibliographic entry `@type`s, please refer to: [Bibliography Management from LaTeX WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX)

Therefore, I experimented with other standard `@type`s to see if I can get the desired result. However, all other `@type`s I tested proved useless to render the desired result. So, with a cheeky hack to the original `@inproceedings` format, I was able to get the desired result. It may be a dirty hack, but it's effective nonetheless! :) Here's what I did:

```
%%%%%% begin: modified citation! %%%%%%
@inproceedings{erdm_13mod_cheat,
  title={blah blah},
  author={blah blah},
  booktitle={SPIE Advanced Lithography, {\upshape 86791Q--86791Q}},
  year={2013},
  organization={blah blah}
}
%%%%%% end: modified citation! %%%%%%
```

The `pages={86791Q--86791Q},` sub-entry was deleted from the `@inproceedings` format and instead, added to the `booktitle` sub-entry as: `booktitle={SPIE Advanced Lithography, {\upshape 86791Q--86791Q}},`. This hack will produce exactly what you need!

Also, there were few other small modifications to what you had provided:

1. Since, you are using `twopage` class option, I had to add `openany` to the list of optional arguments to `\documentclass[...]{scrbook}`, to avoide printing an additional blank page before the bibliography. If you do not want this, just remove it!
2. As @bernard rightly points out in the comment above, you are using two different bibliography style calls: `plainnat` & `unsrtnat`. You can use only one. So, I assume `plainnat` as the bibliography style in my solution.
3. The `filecontents` package allows me to include native BibTeX code in the same TeX document; which makes it easier for everyone to see its contents.
4. To show the difference between original and modified citation, I edited the second line from the main text body to include the modified citation reference, like so:

   ```
   \noindent genetic\cite{erdm_13mod_cheat} algorithms integrated \cite{erdmann2013modeling}.
   ```

Compare the first and the second citation entries from the output Bibliography. First is due to the modified `@inproceedings` format and second is due to the original format which you have used.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,openany,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{erdmann2013modeling,
  title={Modeling studies on alternative EUV mask concepts for higher {NA}},
  author={Erdmann, Andreas and Fuehner, Tim and Evanschitzky, Peter and Neumann, Jens Timo and Ruoff, Johannes and Graeupner, Paul},
  booktitle={SPIE Advanced Lithography},
  pages={86791Q--86791Q},
  year={2013},
  organization={International Society for Optics and Photonics}
}
%%%%%% begin: modified citation! %%%%%%
@inproceedings{erdm_13mod_cheat,
  title={Modeling studies on alternative EUV mask concepts for higher NA},
  author={Erdmann, Andreas and Fuehner, Tim and Evanschitzky, Peter and Neumann, Jens Timo and Ruoff, Johannes and Graeupner, Paul},
  booktitle={SPIE Advanced Lithography, {\upshape 86791Q--86791Q}},
  year={2013},
  organization={International Society for Optics and Photonics}
}
%%%%%% end: modified citation! %%%%%%
@article{fuhner2007direct,
  title={Direct optimization approach for lithographic process conditions},
  author={F{\"u}hner, Tim and Erdmann, Andreas and Seifert, Sebastian},
  journal={Journal of Micro/Nanolithography, MEMS, and MOEMS},
  volume={6},
  number={3},
  pages={{031006--031006}},
  year={2007},
  publisher={International Society for Optics and Photonics}
}
\end{filecontents}

\hbadness=10000 % For Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) warning!

\begin{document}
\noindent solution\cite{fuhner2007direct}.\\[10pt]
\noindent genetic\cite{erdm_13mod_cheat} algorithms integrated \cite{erdmann2013modeling}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you do. It uses `biblatex`.The default style is `numeric`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{pages.bib}
@article{LbyLgraphic,
author = {M. Yamamoto and T. Namioka},
title = {{Layer-by-layer design method for soft-x-ray multilayers}},
journal = {Applied Opticas},
pages = {{1622--1630}},
year = 1992
}
@article{Erd,
author = {A. Erdmann and al. },
title = {{Multiple studies on alternative EUV mask concepts fir higher NA}},
journal = {Proc. of SPIE},
pages = {{86791Q-1}--{86791Q-12}},
year = 2013
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{pages.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
page = {},
pages = {}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1\isdot}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\relax}

\begin{document} As we see in \cite{LbyLgraphic} and \cite{Erd}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: You're. I've forgotten  to simplify the O.P.'s code. I wonder why this convoluted way of inserting a dash?

Comment: I really donot understand this code. Because my thesis is organised in a different way. could you take a look at my editted question again?thanks!!!

Comment: I can only help with `biblatex`. This is a code that patches the default style of  biblatex. The information from the original post was 1. numeric style. 2. Just page numbers. I can emulate your new code with `biblatex`, which has a `natbib` option for that.

Comment: You have two bibliography style calls: `plainat` and `unsrtnat`. Which one do you really use?